# Running Jmeter from execute shell on Jenkins

Tags: command-line, maven-2, jenkins, jmeter

After building the maven projects I'd like to run the jmeter tests independently. I go to the jmeter bin folder and execute:

```
jmeter -n -t $jmxFile -l $jtlFile
```

but I get the error:

```
/tmp/hudson2322728548480325736.sh: line 7: jmeter: command not found
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
```

What commands can I use?

Say I have the jmx files under one particular folder. If there is another way to run these tests, please let me know.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Any news on that, was my answer OK ? I think it is but I would like some feedback

Answer (score 3):

Ensure jmeter is on user running jenkins path.
Another option is to put the full path to jmeter.
A third one to use maven plugins, see:

- [What maven plugin is to be used for JMeter? jmeter-maven-plugin or chronos-jmeter-maven-plugin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11740920/what-maven-plugin-is-to-be-user-for-jmeter-jmeter-maven-plugin-or-chronos-jmete)

Answer (score 0):

you can also checkout how we added JMeter tests to Jenkins:

http://ibalosh.tumblr.com/post/35475979058/running-jmeter-tests-with-jenkins

might help
Igor